# Android Studio 3.0 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2

Tags: android, android-studio

*I updated the emulater android Studio 3.0,but when i started it didn't work and lanuch ..just errors in log,any help thanks in advance*

```
 Emulator: [1672]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt 
 library not found at C:\mypath\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
```

`Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\mypathemulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory also Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2`